# Explain the use of Jenkins for php projects

Tags: jenkins

I know this may sound little idiotic or annoying  but i really dont have any idea why we use **Jenkins**  for PHP development and how is it useful and helpful to a developer.
and if so then how to start for it.

Thanks in advance 
Anand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins can be used for :

- Running automated tests (you have to write them before)

You have to write unit tests with PHPUnit for exemple. You can also write functionnal test with Selenium.
Jenkins will automatically run tests and create reports

- Auto test your database schemas evolutions

For exemple, with Postgresql you have a lot of commands to create, restore and dump database.

- Deploy your application to pre-production or production environment.

Using git to deploy an app is very simple with Jenkins.

- Static analysis of the source code with SonarQube
- Interact with a git repositery (put tags, ...)

If you begin with Jenkins, you can take a look here : [Jenkins Documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/). You can also check BlueOcean for a better UI.

Comment: Thanks JulienCsj it is really helpful

Answer (score 0):

With Jenkins you can automate the simplest tasks in your project like:

- execute builds and tests for every commit made in your repository
- check your code for bugs, code smells and vulnerabilities
- automatically deploying your software on a web server or in a docker container
- archive build artifacts in a artifact repository
- and much more ...

So basically, Jenkins gives you feedback on the status of your application. Continuous Integration is essential for every project (not just PHP, Java, C# ...) and it is considered to improve quality.